# laravel 7 calling a method function for delete a file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

i tried now long enough how i call the delete function from my mediacontroller in my media index.blade. I dont get it. So if someone of you give me a tipp please answer! I would really appreciate it!

Thats my media index.blade.php:

```
<div class="container">


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">


            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3>Upload</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{"upload"}}">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="media"
                                       aria-describedby="media" name="file">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="media">Datei auswählen</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('file')
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        @enderror
                        <hr/>
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Hochladen</button>
                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h1>Media</h1>
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">

                    <form action="{{route('media.index')}}" method="GET" role="search">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" value="{{request()->input("q")}}"
                                   placeholder="Suche...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">
                                    <span class="fa  fa-search"></span>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <br/>
                    @if($medias->count() > 0 )

                        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Dateiname</th>
                            <th>Extension</th>
                            <th>Größe</th>
                            <th>Preview</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($medias as $media)
                                <tr>

                                    <td>{{$media->id}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$media->name}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$media->extension}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$media->size}}</td>

                                    <td><a href="{{route('media', $media->id)}}">
                                            @if(in_array($media->extension, ["jpg", "jpeg", "bpm", "png", "gif"]))
                                                <img src="{{route("media", $media->id)}}" width="150"/>
                                            @else
                                                @switch($media->extension)
                                                    @case("pdf")
                                                    <i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i>

                                                    @break

                                                    @case("xsls")
                                                    <i class="fa fa-file-excel"></i>

                                                    @break

                                                    @case("doc")
                                                    <i class="fa fa-file-word"></i>

                                                    @break

                                                    @case("docx")
                                                    <i class="fa fa-file-word"></i>

                                                    @break

                                                    @case("svg")
                                                    <i class="fa fa-vector-square"></i>

                                                    @break

                                                @endswitch
                                            @endif
                                        </a></td>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><a href="{{ route('media.delete', [$media->id]) }}" class="btn btn-danger"> <i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    @else
                        <h4>Es wurden keine Daten gefunden</h4>
                    @endif
                    {{$medias->links()}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now my web.php with the routes:

```
Route::resource("kitas", "KitaController");
Route::resource("users", "UserController");
Route::resource("posts", "PostController");
Route::post("/upload", "MediaController@upload")->name("upload");
Route::get("media", "MediaController@index")->name("media.index");
Route::get("media/{id}/delete", "MediaController@index")->name("media.delete");
Route::get("/media/{id}", "MediaController@download")->name("media");
Route::get("/media/{id}/preview", "MediaController@preview")->name("media.preview");
```

and now my MediaController:

```
class MediaController extends Controller


public function index() {

    $q = request()->input("q");
    if($q) {
        $medias=    Media::where('name','LIKE','%'.$q.'%')->orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(10);
    }else {
        $medias = Media::orderByDesc('created_at')->paginate(10);
    }

    return view("media.index")->with(["medias" => $medias]);
}

public function upload( Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        "file" => "required"
    ]);
    $name = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = $request->file("file")->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $size = $request->file("file")->getSize();
    $path = $request->file("file")->store("public/media");
   Media::create([
       "name" => $name,
       "extension" => $extension,
       "size" => $size,
       "path" => $path
   ]);
   return redirect()->route("media.index")->withStatus("Datei wurde erfolgreich hochgeladen!");

}

public function download($id)
{
    $media = Media::find($id);
    $file = storage_path(). "/app/". $media->path;
   return response()->file($file);
}

public function preview($id)
{
    $media = Media::whereIn('extension', ["jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp"])->where("id", "=", $id)->first();
    $file = storage_path(). "/app/". $media->path;
    $preview = Image::make($file)->resize(200, 200);
    return $preview->response();
}

public function delete($id)
{
    $media = Media::find($id);
    $media -> delete();
}
```

I can click the delete buttons on the website, but nothing happens.

I cant find the solution. or work it out for myself. the sheer amount of different ways you can solve things with coding drives me nuts. I try to code now for like 9 months and i just get slowly forward, since Iam more used to have one solution to get to the goal not 500 differnt ones. Makes me a bit upset to get behind all the stuff.

Do you have also tipps how to learn to code from zero to hero?

thanks!

Pommesfee

Answer (score 0):

The default `delete` route generated by a resourceful route like

```
Route::resource("foo", "FooController");
```

will only accept a `DELETE` request.

Now, there isn't actually a `DELETE` method for a HTML Form so you will need to do what Laravel refers to as "Form Method Spoofing"

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#form-method-spoofing

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
</form>
```

If you are looking for a good resource to learn Laravel (and other related frameworks), i would suggest [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/)

---

**Addendum**

You are specifying a `GET` request which will not work. You should specify a `DELETE` request like so:

```
Route::delete("media/{id}/delete", "MediaController@index")->name("media.delete");
```

You also need to use the `POST` method on the form AND add the form model spoofing like so:

```
<form action="{{ route('media.delete', [$media->id]) }} method="POST">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: See the updates to my answer and good luck. The devil is in the details ;)

Answer (score 0):

SO, thats my delete route:

```
Route::get("media/{id}/delete", "MediaController@index")->name("media.delete");
```

and that would be the button to delete the image?

```
<form action="{{ route('media.delete', [$media->id]) }} method="DELETE">
      @method('DELETE')
      @csrf
</form>
```

I dont get behind about that and how to transfer it to my needs.